# http.Server.ListenAndServe Crash "too many commas" On Minikube Only

Tags: go, minikube

I have a server written in Go that presents a REST API.  This service runs fine on MacOS, and also as a cross-compiled Linux executable in a Docker container. And for a few days, it ran fine deployed in minikube as well. Somehow it has quit working on minikube, failing with an "address has too many commas" error. I have tried various flavors of Addr specification, all with the same result -- works everywhere but minikube.

```
// Configure http server
srv := &http.Server{
    Handler: r,
    Addr:    ":8087",
    WriteTimeout: 15 * time.Second,
    ReadTimeout:  15 * time.Second,
}

// Listen to configured port and serve
log.Fatal(srv.ListenAndServe())
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:latest
WORKDIR /home
COPY ./bin/afg-linux afg
EXPOSE 8087
RUN chmod +x afg
CMD ./afg
```

And the minikube YAML:

```
# APP DEPLOYMENT
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    run: afg
  name: afg
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: afg-ex
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: afg-ex
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: localhost:5000/afg:v1.02
        name: afg
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8087
          protocol: TCP
---
# APP SERVICE
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    run: afg
  name: afg
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8087
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8087
  selector:
    run: afg-ex
  type: NodePort
```

Comment: What exactly this expression evaluates to `"0.0.0.0" + ":" + config.Listen,`

Comment: The error message is:

    `listen tcp: address 0.0.0.0:tcp://10.101.224.10:8087: too many colons in address`

Apparently, the IP dynamically allocated by minikube is being injected to the address, but without properly replacing the "0.0.0.0", which is a sort of IPv4 wildcard binding.  Changing the declaration of that in the code seems to have no effect, as the extra leading colon is always there.  The address probably should have been transformed to `tcp://10.101.224.10:8087`

Comment: `0.0.0.0:tcp://10.101.224.10:8087` --- this is totally wrong syntax though. Where do you get `config.Listen` from? Regardless of where - it contains an unexpected value.

Comment: The config object is populated by environment variables.  config.Listen is the port to listen on.  FWIW, this same code runs fine in many other contexts.

Comment: FWIW, changing the Addr value to `":" + config.Listen` produces the same error, just now slightly different flavor:  
`listen tcp: address :tcp://10.101.224.10:8087: too many colons in address`

Comment: as does `Addr = ":8087"`, which is the format shown in the docs.

Comment: I'm lost at the moment - show the very actual version of code you're running and the exact `config.Listen` value. `:tcp://10.101.224.10:8087` is wrong syntax. `0.0.0.0:tcp://10.101.224.10:8087` is wrong syntax as well, so both fail *as expected*.

Comment: Exactly -- I do not provide either of those strings.  That is indeed the problem.  I just put in the port as shown in the Go docs.  Runs in MacOs, runs in Docker, runs in GKE, doesn't run in minikube.

Comment: `config.Listen` is a variable (technically: a structure's field) that is provided by something somewhere. Where is it set? Wherever it is set - it is set to the wrong value.

Comment: It is set using Cobra.  I have also tested just putting in the literal string ":8087" into Server.Addr.  Same results -- too many commas.  The Go docs use ":8080", but I doubt the port number is the issue.

Comment: The issue is that **you** pass `tcp://10.101.224.10:8087` there. You only should pass a single number there. Anyway, we're going circles, the problem is that you're passing wrong value. If you pass the correct value (a number) it would be fine.

Comment: I do NOT pass that value.  I pass ":8087".  BTW, if I pass "8087", Go says I'm missing the port.  This is why they require the colon in front of the number in the docs.

Comment: Sure, if you pass the proper `ip:port` (or `:port`) value it would be okay, but you or whatever software you use - passes the wrong value. What kind of help are you seeking for?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172119/discussion-between-zerkms-and-user127).